# in-app billing issue with IabHelper

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm using the in-app billing tutorial to start implementation.

- I downloaded the sample app
- Got my key from the developer console
- Put the proper permissions in my manifest
- Got the aidl file and all of the util java files into my project and implemented the following code into my onCreate event...

  ```
  if (GooglePlayVersion)
  {
      try
      {   
      mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
      mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
             public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess())
                   // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                   debugLog("Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result, 0);          
                debugLog("IAB got bound", 0); 
             }
          });
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          debugLog("iab exception " + e.getMessage(), 1);
      }
  }
  ```

My app blows on the mHelper.startsetup line. No Exception. When I step through, once I leave that line debugging never goes to the next line. My app never starts up. Of course if I set GooglePlayVersion to false everything runs ok.

EDIT: Since my post yesterday I found that an exception was indeed being thrown by the mHelper.startSetup line.  `Stored Exception Found Binder invocation to an incorrect interface [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@405a8478`.

I have found post by others with this exception and it was suggested that maybe my aidl file does not match the in-billing interface.  I got the aidl file from the downloaded trivialdrivessample program changing only the package line.

Answer (score 7):

You should not change the package name of the aidl file. Put the aidl file in your src directory under *com.android.vending.billing* package.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem though I followed the instructions from Google Android website step by step. They haven't clearly and correctly mentioned where to change package names. So in order to fix it, if you move the .aidl file to let say com.myawesome.app.main, then you have not only to change package declaration in the headers of all the files, but also in this line inside the labHelper.java file:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.myawesome.app.main.InAppBillingService.BIND");
```

The default which you do not want is:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
```

This fixed it for me and hope it'll fix it for you as well.

Comment: I would guess you should also change IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION

Comment: "app" would be the main module, and "main" the name of the main activity as defined in "android:name" of AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Gary, It seems like you are having startup challenges with In-App billing. Its not a new issue. In-app billing is a real pain to get working. A lot of people have pain getting it working. I recommend that you first get it working standalone. And then integrate the working piece of project to your code. I recommend [this](http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/integrate-in-app-billing-just-3-lines-of-code-in-your-app/).

Other links can be found on stackoverflow, I wont do a search at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up and the link.  I've decided to put the app on the marketplace without in-app billing first and then work those issues for the next version.

Comment: Good call, the api's are really badly written. So it will take you dedicated effort to get it integrated. But once its there, its stable. That said, I hear that 4.0 has fixed this. Still need to research it.

Comment: Siddharth: Any news on 4.0?  It's time for me to make a decision to wait for 4 or implement 3. thanks

Comment: 3.0 I think was a failure, I think you mean 2.3.x. Yes 4.0 has fixed and made inapp billing easier.

Comment: I'm confused regarding this comment thread; I think that Siddharth is talking about Android 4.0 (e.g., ICS) fixing certain problems in its interaction with IAB 3, but then user1058647 seems to think that there is an IAB version 4 coming out to replace IAB version 3?

user1058647, so far as I know, there is no IAB version 4 in the works, if that was what you were thinking.  Hence, no need to wait for it.

Could you guys clarify on this just so I know I've properly understood your comments?  Tx.

Comment: I am referring to Android versions here. 4.0 Android has fixed some of its issues in documentation and the API's. Its easier and cleaner to integrate In-App now.